# Cross Domain Tracking with Global Site Tag - What goes where?

Tags: google-analytics

Having some issues with the implementation of cross domain tracking with the Gtag.js. I'm trying to do CDT for a restaurant website which has an external booking system with a 5 different URLs (1 for each restaurant booking system). I'm using the same GA property, but have failed to figure out if the Gtag.js is set up correctly. Here's what I have on the restaurant business domain:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX- 
1"> 
</script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', {
'linker': {
    'domains' [  
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage1.com', 
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage2.com',
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage3.com',
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage4.com',
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage5.com'] 
      }
   });
</script>
```

Then, on the restaurant.bookingpage1-5, I should implement:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA- 
XXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', {
'linker': {
'accept_incoming': true

}
});

</script>
```

Afterwards, I implemented the restaurant main domain as a referral exclusion in Analytics.

Can anyone see if this is correctly set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the colon after `domains`

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', {
'linker': {
    'domains' [
```

Comment: Ms. Easy, Thanks! 

- Do you have any comments regarding the remaining code? Is it the right setup for Cross Domain Tracking with the different domains? 

Appreciate it!

Comment: @MadsK Yes, setting is ok. Note that it is one-sided cross-domain tracking: user visits site A and then goes to site B. If user can visit site B at first, you need two-sided cross domain tracking.

Comment: Yes, thanks! 
I've tried to implement the code on both domains and the code doesn't have any bugs as far as I can tell. However, when in debug mode, the client ID still changes when entering one of the booking domains? 

All of the booking domains are actually a part of the same root domain, but they have different IDs attached to the URL (ex. https://restaurant.bookingpage1.com/UniqueRestaurantID/1234 and for another restaurant: https://restaurant.bookingpage1.com/UniqueRestaurantID/4321)

All booking sites have independent headers so it should work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @MadsK Did you add linked domains in Referral exclusion list in GA?

Comment: yes, I added the root domain to the referral exclusion list. GA only allows me to put in the main domain and not the subpages. Since my gtag is not installed on the main domain and only on the 6 different landing pages (in 6 different headers), could that be the issue?

Comment: @MadsK Soryy, it's difficilt to understand. " GA only allows me to put in the main domain and not the subpages. " what does it mean?

Comment: okay, sorry. I mean that I can't add a specific landing page to the referral exclusion list in GA, but only the main domain. Fx I can add www.domain.com to the referral exclusion list, but not www.domain.com/landing-page-example. I'm not sure if this has impact on the results of CDT (to me it shouldn't). Do you perhaps have an example of a website that's using this setup so I can see their code? I don't know anyone who's doing CDT from gtag.js, but only analytics.js or through an AMP.

Comment: You need to add domain to exlusion list, not landing page. How one domain linked with other? Just link or using iframe?

Comment: The domain is already excluded in GA (www.domain.com) but since it didn't work, I thought maybe that was the error. It's a regular "Book Now" Button CTA that's been implemented on the site. That sends the customer to the booking site.

Comment: In the gtag script of the restaurant website, I've added the list of domains as www.bookingsite.com/restaurant1, www.bookingsite.com/restaurant2. All the 5 different booking sites have the same main domain (www.bookingsite.com), so should I just add that 1 domain in the code instead of the 5 different landing pages? Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Of course, 1 domain.But in your example were different domains like this 'https://restaurant.bookingpage1.com'.

Comment: Yes, my example was a bit misleading for this case actually. I have inserted 5 different landing pages under 1 domain, fx:
    'domains' [  
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage.com/restaurant-1', 
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage.com/restaurant-2',
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage.com/restaurant-3',
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage.com/restaurant-4',
            'https://restaurant.bookingpage.com/restaurant-5']

This is the mistake, you believe?